# Object must be a type of string property in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf

Having model with property type of object.

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    private object _BirthDate;
    public object BirthDate
    {
        get { return this._BirthDate; }
        set
        {
            this._BirthDate = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("BirthDate");
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

Populating data for BirthDate like in below.

```
if (i % 5 == 0)
{
    emp.BirthDate = "ABC";
    //  emp.Name = "NUll";
}
else if (i % 4 == 0)
{
    emp.BirthDate = null;
    // emp.Name = "DBNull";
}
else
    emp.BirthDate = new DateTime(1 / 1 / 2013);
```

Having 100 birthdates. i am try to sort the data using LINQ query with LAMDA exressions.

```
private void GetSortedQuerableCollection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var sourceType = new Employee().GetType();

    var source = (this.datagrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable).AsQueryable() as IQueryable;
    var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, sourceType.Name);
    var lambda = GetLambdaWithComplexPropertyNullCheck(source, "BirthDate", paramExpression, sourceType);

    var data = OrderBy(source, "BirthDate", sourceType);
}
```

In data, having the results with "Object Must be a type of String".

Note: GetLambdaWithComplexPropertyNullCheck is the method having lots of code. if i include that also, its look inconsistency , and as per StackOverFlow norm its deletes the page. but it just a expression to calculate the sorting.

Let me have any idea to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I'm unclear where the problem is. What doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to try to sort on "ABC", null, and a DateTime value. You will have to rethink this concept. Actually, the fact that you have to use `object`, should turn on a red lamp.

Comment: @Filburt: I notice you made an edit with comment "removed fluff" but you actually changed some of the code in there too. Is this intentional? It removes actual use of `lambda` from the code...

Comment: @Chris The highlighted edit to the code was not intended. I suspect this must be a concurrent edit and the OP ignored the warning about the post being edited.

Comment: Hi @Gustav,

actually we using the BirthDate property as the column in grid. when we try to edit the value with string value as it can be accept any type due to type is object and its commit the edited value.

after committing the edited value i am trying to sort that column , where we are getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to mix dates, null, and non-dates, then use string:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string = null;
    public string BirthDate
    {
        get { return this._BirthDate; }
        set
        {
            this._BirthDate = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("BirthDate");
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
emp.BirthDate = new DateTime(2013, 1 , 21).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
```

This is sortable, and you can easily parse BirthDate to a DateTime value:

```
DateTime trueDate = DateTime.Parse(emp.BirthDate);
```

Comment: We can avoid the exception by above ways. But, Can we avoid with the type of object ?

Comment: I don't think so. It must be sortable - which a string is.

Comment: Please let me have any reference why we cannot done with object.

Comment: I have not tested it, but this link seems to demonstrate a way to workaround it: [How to Make Your Class Sortable](https://csbubblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/howto-sortable/).